# How to make nav drawer item background color span the whole drawer and become unclickable?

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, background-color, navigationitem

Below is a screenshot and files for my nav drawer. Currently, the yellow background on "Features - Day of Event" and the others only spans the title when it should span the entire nav drawer view with the text left-aligned instead of in line with the other items. Also, the items with the yellow background are clickable and although they don't go anywhere, they close the nav bar when they shouldn't. I apologize in advance as I've inherited this project from someone else and have no prior experience with android studio. Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of nav drawer]

MainActivity.java snippet; this is where the nav drawer items seem to get their color:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem features= menu.findItem(R.id.features);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(features.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FDDA24")), 0, s.length(), 0);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), 0, s.length(), 0);
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, s.length(), 0);
    features.setTitle(s);

    Menu menu1 = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem social_media= menu1.findItem(R.id.social_media);
    SpannableString t = new SpannableString(social_media.getTitle());
    t.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FDDA24")), 0, t.length(), 0);
    t.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), 0, t.length(), 0);
    t.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, t.length(), 0);
    social_media.setTitle(t);

    MenuItem app_guide= menu.findItem(R.id.app_guide);
    SpannableString u = new SpannableString(app_guide.getTitle());
    u.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FDDA24")), 0, u.length(), 0);
    u.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), 0, u.length(), 0);
    u.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, u.length(), 0);
    app_guide.setTitle(u);
```

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/features"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="Features - Day Of Event"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/upcoming_drawings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_current_raffle"
                android:title="Current and Upcoming Drawings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/track_your_tickets"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_winning_numbers"
                android:title="Winning Raffle Numbers" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/main_stage"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_main_stage"
                android:title="Concert and Main Stage" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/strip_tickets_and_other_raffles"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_other_raffles"
                android:title="Strip Tickets and Other Raffles" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/maps_and_directions"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_maps"
                android:title="Maps and Directions" />
        </group>
    <item android:title="Social Media" android:id="@+id/social_media"/>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/twitter"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter"
                android:title="Twitter"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                android:title="Facebook"/>
        </group>
    <item android:title="Grand Bash App Guide" android:id="@+id/app_guide"/>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/discover_the_bash"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_discover"
                android:title="Discover the Bash"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/faq"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_faq"
                android:title="FAQ"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/rules"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_rules"
                android:title="Rules"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/contact"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact"
                android:title="Contact"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/account_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_settings"
                android:title="Account Settings"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/buy_tickets"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_buy_tickets"
                android:title="Buy Tickets"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/event_sponsors"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event_sponsors"
                android:title="Event Sponsors"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/monthly_raffles"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_monthly_raffles"
                android:title="Monthly Raffles"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/vip_tables"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_vip"
                android:title="VIP Tables"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/volunteers"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_volunteer"
                android:title="Volunteers"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
                android:title="Info"/>
        </group>
```